# OneToOneField Relationship Not Created

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form in which I take the data from some of the fields and create a new model object, then assign that newly created object a one-to-one relationship to a preexisting object of a different model. Here is my save method in the form.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomerProfileForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.cleaned_data['street_address']:
        if not self.instance.customer.home_location:
            home_location = Location()
        else :
            home_location = self.instance.customer.home_location
        home_location.name = 'Home/Apartment'
        home_location.street_address = self.cleaned_data['street_address']
        home_location.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        home_location.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        home_location.zip_code = self.cleaned_data['zip_code']
        self.instance.customer.home_location = home_location
        home_location.save()
        self.instance.customer.save()

    return self.instance
```

The Location object is being created and populated with the information from the form as I expect, but the OneToOne relationship with the CustomerProfile object (self.instance) is not being assigned. Does anyone know why this might be?

This makes no sense to me. When I print `self.instance.customer.home_location` right before the end of the save function, the new location is logged to the console, which shows that the relationship is assigned... How does it get unassigned after the save method completes...?

Comment: You need to save the location first before you can assign it as a foreign key. Put `home_location.save()` before your `self.instance.customer.home_location = home_location` line.

Comment: Yep... that did the trick. Such a simple thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save a relationship, the object needs to have a primary key; and this is only generated after the object is saved.

Therefore, you need to save the object first, before assigning it as a foreign key:

```
    home_location.save()
    self.instance.customer.home_location = home_location
    # home_location.save() - this line should come before any relationships
    #                        are linked to the object.
    self.instance.customer.save()
```